# End python code without error keep Gui open

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a tkinter gui that has a button that starts a process.  During this process there is an if statement, if this statement is true then then the process ends.  When the process ends I want the GUI to be kept open and not show an error. I've tried os._exit() but it closes the gui as well.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
def Program():
#Process
#Process
    if #something happens#:
       #Stop process but keep gui open and dont show errors
root = Tk()
root.title("GUI")
root.geometry('450x300+200+200')
labelText=StringVar()
labelText.set("Program")
label1=Label(root,textvariable=labelText,height=4)
label1.pack()
mbutton=Button(text='Start Program',command=Model).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: is your process another function would `return` not work?

Answer (score 0):

You could run GUI in the main thread and put the part that should terminate independently in a background thread. Add try/except in the thread to suppress traceback e.g.:

```
import threading

def bgthread(gui_ready, result_queue):
    gui_ready.wait()
    while True:
       try:
           # do some work ...
           result_queue.put(result) # GUI gets results e.g., 
                                    # via q.get_nowait() in a
                                    # widget.after() callback 
           if something_happened():
              break # exit
       except: #NOTE: don't use bare except unless it is absolutely necessary
           logger.error() # log to file
           break # exit

# setup logging          
# ...
ready = threading.Event()
q = Queue.Queue()
threading.Thread(target=bgthread, args=(ready,q)).start()

# setup gui here
...
root.mainloop() # call ready.set() in some GUI code then it is ready
```

Answer (score 0):

Python code worked using geo_pythoncl suggestion of using return.

```
from Tkinter import * 
import tkMessageBox 
def Program(): 
#Process 
#Process     
 if #something happens#:        
 #Stop process but keep gui open and dont show errors 
 return
root = Tk() 
root.title("GUI") 
root.geometry('450x300+200+200') 
labelText=StringVar() 
labelText.set("Program") 
label1=Label(root,textvariable=labelText,height=4) 
label1.pack() 
mbutton=Button(text='Start Program',command=Model).pack() 
root.mainloop()
```